# Command line arguments are not passed in Windows 7 - Java

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

I am running a executable jar using batch which expects command line arguments.

```
ECHO OFF  
java -jar myjar.jar %1 %2 %3 %CD% 
PAUSE
```

I checked the code on one windows system and works fine. I am running it on another windows 7 system, but the command line arguments are not passed to the jar. The args.length gives me 0. I have checked the following:

```
C:\Users> assoc .jar  
.jar=jarfile
C:\Users> ftype jarfile
jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

I have also tested a simple batch file to ECHO a command line argument, and it works fine. I accepts the argument and prints it.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the full text of an example batch file that we can run with our own jars?

Comment: Force `echo ON` in the batch file where the `java -jar myjar.jar %1 %2` line resides. Then you could see possible culprit...

Comment: @KevinWorkman i edited the question to include the complete batch code

Comment: @JosefZ when I force     echo on  i get: C:\Users>java -jar myjar.jar   The arguments are missing.

Comment: Launching `yourbat.bat par1 "par 2" par3` should show `java -jar myjar.jar par1 "par 2" par3 ` followed up by expanded `%CD%` variable.

Comment: exactly but its not showing the arguments i pass when I have ECHO ON.

Comment: If any of your parameter(s) contains some _special_ characters e.g. `< > & |` enclose _all_ parameters supplied in a pair of double quotes (severally) as follows: `yourbat.bat "par1" "par 2" "par3"`  (the `java` should cope with double quoted parameters with no problem). Show us parameters supplied.

Comment: I do not have any such special characters. And like I have mentioned, I have tested it with same structure and arguments in another windows 7 system and it works fine. I read somewhere that sometimes the registry is not properly defined which disables the passing of the arguments. That's why I checked the ftype for jar but it is enabled. And for the system as well the argument is working. I am totally confused what approach to take. Thanks a lot for taking time on it. I was wondering if anyone has ever came across this kind of issue.

Comment: Posting a screenshot (with echoing turned on) might help.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved. I think the answer might seem to be very silly, but since I posted the question so I would just go ahead. So the problem was that I was running Java Runtime Environment, it got resolved when I installed Development Kit instead. But what I'm quite confused about is that, I installed the Runtime Environment on the other Windows 7 system and it worked fine, why did it didn't work and needed JDK instead for this system running windows 7 as well. Thank you everyone for taking time. I would really appreciate it if anybody knows why did it act this way and just mention it.